# Racket and 2htdp/image in the terminal

Tags: racket, pict

I don't know how to display images in the terminal.

Here is a .rkt test script:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)

(circle 10 "solid" "red")
```

Then, I do this in the terminal:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.8.
> (enter! "test.rkt")
(object:image% ...)
"test.rkt">
```

So I'm getting `(object:image% ...)` when I should be getting an image of a circle.

How can I get images to display in the terminal?

Comment: Terminal emulators are intrinsically text-based, and they are not usually built to render images. Certain terminal emulators can, like [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/index.html), but this is non-standard and requires special support.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on this question recently as well.
Tried many combinations of keywords searching online and finally found [a working solution](https://www.mail-archive.com/racket-users@googlegroups.com/msg40530.html).

For example,

```
; this approach would NOT render the image
; start repl inside a terminal
$ racket -i
(require 2htdp/image)
(circle 5 "solid" "red")
```

```
; this approach would render the image in a canvas
; start repl inside a terminal
$ racket -i
(require 2htdp/image racket/gui/base (only-in pict show-pict))
(show-pict (circle 5 "solid" "red"))
```

Regarding the comment by @Alexis King, as far as I know, although iTerm2 [could display image](https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html), it would not work inside a `repl`. I could be wrong though and would be happy to know if there are alternatives out there.

I can finally use vim + tmux to play with racket now!